# Publishing CDC with Apex trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, change-data-capture

I've been following/researching a few resources online to create a apex trigger that gets triggered **after** actions on `Account` objects.

I'm trying to test the first bit so far where I want to capture the `entityName`, `changedFields` and `changeType` of the saved changes of an account. I will be publishing them to an endpoint after but right now I'm trying to get the logic on capturing the data correct.

```
trigger MyTrigger on Account (after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) {

    if (Trigger.isInsert) {
        System.Debug('Trigger has been called after Insert.');
        for (Account event : Trigger.new){
            EventBus.ChangeEventHeader header = event.ChangeEventHeader;   // <---- issue here
            String changeEntity = header.entityName;
            List<String> changedFields = header.changedfields;
            String changeOperation = header.changeType;
        }
    }
    else if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
        System.Debug('Trigger has been called after Update.');
    }
    else if (Trigger.isDelete) {
        System.Debug('Trigger has been called after Delete.');
    }
    else if (Trigger.isUndelete) {
        System.Debug('Trigger has been called after UnDelete.');
    }
}
```

The developer console states "Variable does not exist: ChangeEventHeader". Thing is I was following a resource on the salesforce [website](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_trigger_intro.htm). So this isn't really making sense why I cannot call `ChangeEventHeader` that way.

So how do I capture the wanted fields after insert/update etc.. with the apex trigger?

Answer (score 4):

You will want to use the AccountChangeEvent object instead of Account in your trigger header.

```
trigger MyTrigger on AccountChangeEvent (after insert)
```

Comment: I don't have an option for AccountChange only AccountChangeEvent. Is this the same but updated version?

Comment: @pragmaticlearner yeah, I'm on my phone, I probably messed up, lol. But the point is that the Account trigger is incorrect.